# How can I use regex replace to surround each character in a matched group

Tags: regex, cmake

I'm trying to define a regex replace that can convert a string in a matched group and surround each character with quotes.

For example, given the following:

```
#define TEST_1  "Test String"
#define TEST_2  "Another Test String"
```

I'd like to do a regex replace to get:

```
char TEST_1[] = { 'T','e','s','t',' ','S','t','r','i','n','g' };
char TEST_2[] = { 'A','n','o','t','h','e','r',' ','T','e','s','t',' ','S','t','r','i','n','g' };
```

Is there any way to do this in regex, specifically the regex in CMake?

Comment: I don't think this is doable in a regexp.

Comment: You can do it with languages like perl.

Comment: try split('', str)

Comment: regex is replace  `"(.)"` with `",'$1'"` then replace `"^,"` with `""` its unclear if parsing language, but no advise

Comment: Does [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/EwzROm/2) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure it's possible to manipulate an entire line as you requested with one CMake call, but here is one solution that requires a few calls.

Here, we split the initial string on the double-quotes:

```
#define TEST_1  "Test String"
```

into two sections: `#define TEST_1` and `Test String`. Next, we called [`string(REGEX REPLACE ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html#regex-replace) on each section of the string to manipulate it appropriately. Then, we concatenated the two portions back together at the end:

```
# Define an initial string, for testing.
set(MYSTRING "#define TEST_1  \"Test String\"")
message("${MYSTRING}")

# Split the string into the unquoted and quoted portions.
string(REPLACE "\"" ";" MYSTRING_LIST ${MYSTRING})
list(GET MYSTRING_LIST 0 MYSTRING_BEGIN)
list(GET MYSTRING_LIST 1 MYSTRING_QUOTED)

# Perform regex replace to match the '#define TEST_N  ' portion, and
# replace it with 'char TEST_N[] = { '.
string(REGEX REPLACE "^#define TEST_([0-9]+)([ \t\r\n]*)" "char TEST_\\1[] = { " STR_OUTPUT_BEGIN ${MYSTRING_BEGIN})
message("${STR_OUTPUT_BEGIN}")

# Perform regex replace on the quoted string portion, matching every
# character in the string, single-quoting and comma-separating each.
string(REGEX REPLACE "(.)" "'\\1'," STR_OUTPUT_QUOTED ${MYSTRING_QUOTED})
# Remove the trailing comma appended in the previous regex-replace.
string(REGEX REPLACE ",$" "" STR_OUTPUT_QUOTED2 ${STR_OUTPUT_QUOTED})
message("${STR_OUTPUT_QUOTED2}")

# Concatenate them back together, appending the ' };' to the end.
string(CONCAT FINAL_STRING ${STR_OUTPUT_BEGIN} ${STR_OUTPUT_QUOTED2} " };")
message("${FINAL_STRING}")
```

So you can see what's going on, this prints:

```
#define TEST_1  "Test String"
char TEST_1[] = { 
'T','e','s','t',' ','S','t','r','i','n','g'
char TEST_1[] = { 'T','e','s','t',' ','S','t','r','i','n','g' };
```

It should be fairly easy to put this logic into a CMake [`function`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/function.html), and call the function in a loop, if you need to process multiple lines as indicated in your example.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing something similar, using regex on the actual matched part as my actual use case is slightly more complex than the example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample on how to do it

```
set( S "#define TEST_1  \"Test String\"" )             # Set string to beging with
string(REGEX REPLACE "#define[\t ]*([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)" "char \\1[] = { " S ${S} ) # "#define TEST_1" -> "char TEST_1[] = {"
string(REGEX MATCH "\"([^\"]+)\"" RESULT ${S})         # get characters in string
set(RESULT ${CMAKE_MATCH_1})                           # RESULT = Test String
string(REGEX REPLACE "(.)" "'\\1'," RESULT ${RESULT} ) # Replace each character with 'x',
string(LENGTH ${RESULT} iLength)                       # Calculate length
math(EXPR iLength "${iLength} - 1")                    # Decrease length with 1
string(SUBSTRING ${RESULT} 0 ${iLength} RESULT)        # Remove last comma

string(FIND ${S} "{" iPosition)                        # Find {
math(EXPR iPosition "${iPosition} + 1")                # Increase position with 1
string(SUBSTRING ${S} 0 "${iPosition}" S)              # Get substring
string(APPEND FINAL ${S} " " ${RESULT} " };"  )        # Build final string
message( STATUS "FINAL = ${FINAL}" )                   # Print final string
```